# array state not iterable

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

PS- This post is the prime example on how we forget the basic things ...man i am sure feeling dumb XD

I am new Here so stack overflow dosnt let me embed the pics..

I am creating an Ebook management system where i wanted to make favorite book list when i click "add to fav" button on every book

this function is called when i press the "add to fav" button where favList is an empty array state

```
 const [favList, setfavList] = useState([]);

//BookList is an array of books which are fetched from google books API

const addFav = () => {
    return setfavList(
      ...favList,
      BookList.find((t) => id == t.id)
    );
  };
```

But whenever i click multiple books an error occurs
[The Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vtu3H.png)

Here is the declaration of my states
[State Declaration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KrK3.png)

Comment: what is BookList ?

Comment: booklist is the list of books that i am displaying from the booklist i want too add specific books to the favList and then display those in a new component

Comment: You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that people can understand your problem and help you. Add more code, Without sufficient code it is hard to imagine what exactly do you want or what is the problem here?

Comment: What if `Booklist` doesn't find, then it will add unnecessarily `undefined`.

Comment: it will not cause when i will click add to fav the function checks which object in the bookList i am clicking on and then returns the same object. Now i want to save this object in an array state (ie favList) so that i can display the favorite books in another component

Comment: first of all you need to check whether `Booklist is` array or not, them iterate over it.

Comment: This probably isn't it, have you tried placing everything inside setfavList into {}

Comment: never mind i got what was wrong ..the fact that one pair of square braces had me worked up for 4 whole days  :*)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Never mind i found what i had to do

```
const addFav = () => {
    return setfavList([
      ...favList,
      BookList.find((t) => id == t.id)]
    );
  };
```

we all were just missing the square braces yeah kinda lame but thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0):

Are you using hooks, show the code where you declaring the favlist

Try this:

```
const addFav = () => {
if(favList.length)
return setfavList(
  ...favList,
  BookList.find((t) => id == t.id)
);
 else 
    return setfavList(
      BookList.find((t) => id == t.id)
    );
  };
```

Comment: Mate, This is a comment, so you should add it as a comment not as an answer.

Comment: Got it so can you show the declaration of favlist and setfavlist so this can be an actual answer

Comment: i have edited and showed the declaration now

Comment: Now Its an Answer

Comment: i console logged the favList array to check the items ...instead of array it itself became the object .....whenever i click on a new book it updates to new book ....i want that the objects save in the array....this is the problem i am facing  :(

Comment: Do one thing use an empty array and then push new books into it like `addnewbooks =(newbook)=>{ const tempbookList = BookList; tempbookList.push(newbook);setBookList(tempbookList )}`

Comment: you mean instead of updating the state i should create an array and push the books into it and then update the state with the new array?

Comment: Exactly I have edited the comment above have a look

Comment: Ok let me try  that..

Comment: Never mind i found what i had to do
```
const addFav = () => {
    return setfavList([
      ...favList,
      BookList.find((t) => id == t.id)]
    );
  };
```
we all were just missing the square braces yeah kinda lame but tanks for all the help